# How can I delete a JS created LI with a JS created button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a TODO app in JavaScript. How can I understand how to link two created JavaScript items and remove them from the DOM?

**TL;DR:** The place where I keep getting stuck is navigating the DOM after the list item has been created. I have tried to use a a setAttribute to the created elements with an incriminating "id" tag, but I still can figure out how to iterate over the LI's to find which button was pressed.

**Code:**

```
        <div class="entry-field">
          <label class="task-input" for="task-input">Task:</label>
          <input type="text" class="task-field" placeholder="Enter Item"/>
          <button class="add-btn">ADD</button>
        </div>
        <section class="task-list">
          <h2>Task List</h2>
          <div class="list-wrap"></div>
            <ul class="item-log">
              <li class="list-item">
                <span class="item-text">this is the item</span>
                <button class="delete-btn">delete</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

JavaScript:
let index = 0;

//Obtaining user text, creating a Span element, append span with user text:
function addItem() {
  let itemLog = document.querySelector(".item-log");
  let listItem = document.createElement("LI");
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  let userEntry = document.querySelector(".task-field").value;
  let spanItem = document.createElement("SPAN");
  index++;
  //Creating LI "list-item" and append UL "itemLog"
  itemLog.appendChild(listItem);
  listItem.classList.add("list-item");

  listItem.setAttribute("id", index);
  //Create Span element, assign text from user input, append LI
  spanItem.innerHTML = userEntry;
  listItem.appendChild(spanItem);
  //Create deleteBtn and append to LI
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-btn");
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteItem()");
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("id", index);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  userEntry.value = "";
}

/*
2) Deleting item from list:
  -use event listener to trigger parent node
  -delete child
  */

function deleteItem() {
  let listItem = this.parentElement;
  listItem.parentElement.removeChild(listItem);
}

// Page event listeners
let addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your example is what `this` refers to  in your `deleteItem` function. If you console.log it in the `deleteItem` function you'll see that `this` refers to the window not the button pressed.

If instead of using `setAttribute` to set the `onClick`, you can add an event listener:
`deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);`

Inside the `deleteItem` function you'll have access to the event object, as well as the target of that event, and your code will work as expected.

```
function deleteItem(event) {
  let listItem = event.target.parentElement;
  listItem.parentElement.removeChild(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was a simple solution. My question in understanding the solution is: Why must the delete function go inside the addItem() function? I assume it has to do with scope, but I dont understand why it cant live outside the function for organization sake,

Comment: The delete function definition (`function deleteItem(event) { ... }`) does not need to go inside the `addItem` function, just a reference to it (`deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);`).

Answer (score 0):

On any mouse event listener, there will always be a `MouseEvent` parameter passed to the event handler. That `MouseEvent` object has the propertie `target`, which is the `HTMLElement` that was the target of the event. For example:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div.button');
let toggleState = 0;
let messages = ['Clicked!', 'Click me!'];
let handler = function(event) {
  event.target.innerText = messages[toggleState];
  toggleState ^= 1;
}

div.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
```

```html
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
```

In addition, every `HTMLElement` has a `remove()` method, which removes it from the DOM. For example:

```js
document.querySelector('div').remove()
```

or:

```js
let handler = function(event) {
  event.target.remove();
}
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', handler, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Assign a click handler on Delete element creation.
- Create an array of tasks to prepopulate

```js
const myTasks = [
  "This is the item",
  "Well, this is Another item"
];

const EL_text = document.querySelector("#text");
const EL_add = document.querySelector("#add");
const EL_tasks = document.querySelector("#tasks");

function addTask(text) {

  // Determine if we have a text string argument (prepopulate)
  // otherwise grab the input value:
  text = typeof text === 'string' ? text : EL_text.value.trim(); // Trim your values!
  if (!text) return; // do nothing if no value!
  
  const EL_task = document.createElement('li');
  const EL_delete = document.createElement('button');
  
  EL_delete.textContent = "Delete";
  EL_delete.addEventListener('click', () => EL_task.remove());
  
  EL_task.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div>${text}</div>`);
  EL_task.appendChild(EL_delete);
  
  EL_tasks.appendChild(EL_task);
  EL_text.value = ''; // Clear current input text value
}

EL_add.addEventListener("click", addTask);
// Prepopulate
myTasks.forEach(addTask);
```

```css
#tasks {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#tasks li {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.6em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}
#tasks li div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>Task:<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter text"></label>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle - Todo App](https://jsfiddle.net/sdun1p7g/3/)

When creating applications where you must dynamically insert similar elements and track them by an ID system, I recommend a more organized approach to eliminate any confusion in your code.

For basic applications you can create custom classes that each have an `element`, `template`, `ui`, `uiEventCallbacks`, `toggleUIEvents`, and `render` methods. On each class, the `element` is going to be a main HTML element that contains the `template` markup. The `render` method parses the `template` text and assigns it to `element.innerHTML`. To instantiate the application, just create a new instance of the base class, render it, then append the element to body.

I created an Todo Application with your markup. There are `TodoApp`, `Todos`, and `Todo` classes. The `TodoApp` contains `Todos`, and `Todos` contain instances of `Todo`.

**Todo**

```
const Todo = class {
  constructor(settings) {
    this.settings = settings
  }
  get settings() { return this._settings }
  set settings(settings) { this._settings = settings }
  get element() {
    if(!this._element) {
      this._element = document.createElement('li')
      this._element.setAttribute('class', 'list-item')
      this._element.setAttribute('id', this.settings.id )
    }
    return this._element
  }
  get ui() { return {
    deleteButton: this.element.querySelectorAll(':scope > .delete-btn'),
  } }
  get uiEventCallbacks() { return {
    deleteButtonClick: (event) => {
      let customEvent = new CustomEvent('removeTodo', {
        bubbles: true,
        details: {
          id: this.settings.id
        }
      })
      this.element.dispatchEvent(
        customEvent
      )
    },
  } }
  remove() { 
    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element)
    }
  template() { return `
    <span>${this.settings.value}</span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
  ` }
  toggleUIEvents() {
    [
      'removeEventListener',
      'addEventListener'

    ].forEach((eventMethod) => {
      this.ui.deleteButton.item(0)[eventMethod]('click', this.uiEventCallbacks.deleteButtonClick)
    })
  }
  render() {
    const template = this.template()
    this.element.innerHTML = template
    this.toggleUIEvents()
    return this
  }
}
```

**Todos**

```
const Todos = class {
    constructor() {}
  get element() {
    if(!this._element) {
      this._element = document.createElement('section')
      this._element.setAttribute('class', 'task-list')
    }
    return this._element
  }
  get ui() { return {
    itemLog: this.element.querySelectorAll('.item-log')
  } }
  get uiEventCallbacks() { return {
    removeTodo: (event) => {
      console.log(event)
      this.removeTodo()
    },
  } }
  get todos() {
    this._todos = this._todos || []
    return this._todos
  }
  template() { return `
    <h2>Task List</h2>
    <div class="list-wrap">
      <ul class="item-log"></ul>
    </div>
  ` }
  toggleUIEvents() {
    [
      'removeEventListener',
      'addEventListener'
    ].forEach((eventMethod) => {
      this.ui.itemLog.item(0)[eventMethod]('removeTodo', this.uiEventCallbacks.removeTodo)
    })
  }
  addTodo(data) {
    const todo = new Todo(data)
    this.todos.push(todo)
    this.ui.itemLog.item(0).appendChild(
      todo.render().element
    )
    return this
  }
  removeTodo(id) {
    let todoIndex = this.todos.reduce((_todoIndex, todo, todoIndex) => {
      if(todo.id === id) _todoIndex = todoIndex
      return _todoIndex
    }, -1)
    let todo = this.todos.splice(todoIndex, 1)[0]
    todo.remove()
    return this
  }
  render(data) {
    const template = this.template(data)
    this.element.innerHTML = template
    this.toggleUIEvents()
    return this
  }
}
```

**Todo Application**

```
const TodoApp = class {
  constructor() {}
  get element() {
    if(!this._element) {
      this._element = document.createElement('main')
    }
    return this._element
  }
  get ui() { return {
    addButton: this.element.querySelectorAll('.add-btn'),
    input: this.element.querySelectorAll('.task-field'),
  } }
  get uiEventCallbacks() { return {
    addTodo: (event) => {
      let taskFieldData = this.ui.input.item(0).value
      this.todos.addTodo({
        id: this.uuid(),
        value: taskFieldData,
      })
    },
  } }
  get todos() {
    this._todos = this._todos || new Todos()
    return this._todos
  }
  uuid() {
    var uuid = '', i, random
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      random = Math.random() * 16 | 0
      if (i === 8 || i === 12 || i === 16 || i === 20) {
        uuid += "-"
      }
      uuid += (i === 12 ? 4 : (i === 16 ? (random & 3 | 8) : random)).toString(16)
    }
    return uuid
  }
  template() { return `
    <div class="entry-field">
      <label class="task-input" for="task-input">Task:</label>
      <input type="text" class="task-field" placeholder="Enter Item"/>
      <button class="add-btn">ADD</button>
    </div>
  ` }
  toggleUIEvents() {
    [
      'removeEventListener',
      'addEventListener'
    ].forEach((eventMethod) => {
      this.ui.addButton.item(0)[eventMethod]('click', this.uiEventCallbacks.addTodo)
    })
  }
  render(data) {
    const template = this.template(data)
    this.element.innerHTML = template
    this.element.appendChild(this.todos.render().element)
    this.toggleUIEvents()
    return this
  }
}
```

**Instantiate Todo Application**

```
const todoApp = new TodoApp()
const body = document.querySelector('body')
body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', todoApp.render().element)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the recommendation. This method is going to take me a few  days to unpack as my skill level is just not there yet. Do you have any recommendations for resources to learn more about classes and constructors?

Comment: I think MDN is a good introduction. 

- [MDN Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)  

- [MDN Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  

- [MDN ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)  

- [MDN Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)  

- [UUID Generator](https://gist.github.com/jcxplorer/823878)

Comment: In general I do not advocate for declaring variables, defining functions, or performing anything of relative complexity in the global namespace. It is better to encapsulate code using objects and classes. Using object oriented programming techniques and observing popular "design patterns for programming" makes it easier to scale your code. 

I should have included a "base" class for the others to extend from so there is no repetition of functionality, but I wanted to keep it simple. Your message is a reminder that things I believe are simple may be complex for beginners.

Comment: Thanks again, I spend today working through the OOP articles on MDN today. Just opened Pandora's box!

Comment: I think you will find it useful information if you wish to program JavaScript and create dynamic Views. 

Hey - I created a "Plain JS View Class" with description and examples for you to check out. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-v8XWZdsuiRVuxIIf9p4r21VVuOLZGP1yrC4qD76SqU/

It is similar to the impromptu example I shared, but it abstracts the core functionality so you can use it easier.

Comment: This is gold. Thanks again!